# Google Sheets: Conditional formatting on Multiple Rows based on multiple cell values

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to use conditional formatting to color a column based on the value of the column itself, plus another column. But I am having issues.

If the value in H is "Race Expense" and the K cell is empty, I want the K cell to be colored in red. But as you can see below, it is not working. The results I am getting (the colored cells) are incorrect.

[image: spreadsheet sample]

Here's my format condition:

[image: formatting sample]

Here's the actual formula (since you can not see all of it above):

```
=AND(($K667=""),($H667="Race Expense"))
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Well, I feel like a complete idiot. That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I feel like an idiot. Thanks to a comment on my original post the issue is solved.

Since my selected range was K666:K671, I had to modify my formula to use the first row of the range.

I was originally using this formula:

```
=AND(($K667=""),($H667="Race Expense"))
```

But by just changing it to this one it solved the issue:

```
=AND(($K666=""),($H666="Race Expense"))
```